# How to stop the start menu from dissappering below the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

My start menu has picked up this habit of not fully popping when I click it. It happens at random times and is kinda hard to reproduce it at will. It looks like this: [image]

It usually goes back to normal when I either change the orientation of the taskbar and return it to horizontal or sometimes when I open one of the programs at the top of the list. I want to get rid of this quirky behaviour. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is due to the Theme you are using. Have you tried switching to another theme? That should get rid of the problem.
Also, check if you have Aero enabled or not, switching that settings could help as well.

Comment: I tried changing to another aero theme and so far it hasn't misbehaved. I'm going to assume it's fixed.